# xml parsing Python 3 with Beautiful Soup part 2

Tags: xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This is the second part of my previous question ([Parsing xml file using Python3 and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470518/parsing-xml-file-using-python3-and-beautifulsoup/52470626)).

I'm wondering how I parse the following lists, given their different xml structures.  Also, I need to differentiate the different lists (or 'poll titles' in the single xml file.  I can search for the 'results' element, but that element is present in 3 separate lists in the file.

The first poll title xml list uses this code to extract the data.  The 'numplayers = True' argument differentiates this list from the other two, but there is no attribute in the results line for these.

```
for result in soup.find_all('results', numplayers = True):
    numplayers = result['numplayers']
    best = result.find('result', {'value': 'Best'})['numvotes']
    recommended = result.find('result', {'value': 'Recommended'})['numvotes']
    not_recommended = result.find('result', {'value': 'Not Recommended'})['numvotes']
    print (numplayers, best, recommended, not_recommended)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to write something similar to this code for the following two xml lists.  Thank you.

```
<poll title="Language Dependence" name="language_dependence" totalvotes="32">
    <results>
        <result value="No necessary in-game text" numvotes="32" level="1"/>
        <result value="Some necessary text - easily memorized or small crib sheet" numvotes="0" level="2"/>
        <result value="Moderate in-game text - needs crib sheet or paste ups" numvotes="0" level="3"/>
        <result value="Extensive use of text - massive conversion needed to be playable" numvotes="0" level="4"/>
        <result value="Unplayable in another language" numvotes="0" level="5"/>
    </results>
</poll>
<poll title="User Suggested Player Age" name="suggested_playerage" totalvotes="32">
    <results>
        <result value="2" numvotes="0"/>
        <result value="3" numvotes="0"/>
        <result value="4" numvotes="0"/>
        <result value="5" numvotes="1"/>
        <result value="6" numvotes="6"/>
        <result value="8" numvotes="15"/>
        <result value="10" numvotes="10"/>
        <result value="12" numvotes="0"/>
        <result value="14" numvotes="0"/>
        <result value="16" numvotes="0"/>
        <result value="18" numvotes="0"/>
        <result value="21 and up" numvotes="0"/>
    </results>
</poll>
```

Here's what I think should work for the language dependence list, but it doesn't.

```
for result in soup.find_all('result',level=True):
    level = result['level']
    None = result.find('result', {'level': '1'})['numvotes']
    Some = result.find('result', {'level': '2'})['numvotes']
    Mod = result.find('result', {'level': '3'})['numvotes']
    Ext = result.find('result', {'level': '4'})['numvotes']
    Unp = result.find('result', {'level': '5'})['numvotes']
```

Comment: can you share the urls please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use two different condition, see the code below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = """<poll title="Language Dependence" name="language_dependence" totalvotes="32">
    <results>
        <result value="No necessary in-game text" numvotes="32" level="1"/>
        <result value="Some necessary text - easily memorized or small crib sheet" numvotes="0" level="2"/>
        <result value="Moderate in-game text - needs crib sheet or paste ups" numvotes="0" level="3"/>
        <result value="Extensive use of text - massive conversion needed to be playable" numvotes="0" level="4"/>
        <result value="Unplayable in another language" numvotes="0" level="5"/>
    </results>
</poll>
<poll title="User Suggested Player Age" name="suggested_playerage" totalvotes="32">
    <results>
        <result value="2" numvotes="0"/>
        <result value="3" numvotes="0"/>
        <result value="4" numvotes="0"/>
        <result value="5" numvotes="1"/>
        <result value="6" numvotes="6"/>
        <result value="8" numvotes="15"/>
        <result value="10" numvotes="10"/>
        <result value="12" numvotes="0"/>
        <result value="14" numvotes="0"/>
        <result value="16" numvotes="0"/>
        <result value="18" numvotes="0"/>
        <result value="21 and up" numvotes="0"/>
    </results>
</poll>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml,'lxml')
for i in soup.find_all('poll',{'name':'language_dependence'})[0].find_all('result'):
    value = i['value']
    numvotes = i['numvotes']
    level = i['level']
    print('Value:',value,'\n','Numvotes:',numvotes,'\n','Level:',level)
print('--------------------------------------------')   
for i in soup.find_all('poll',{'name':'suggested_playerage'})[0].find_all('result'):
    value = i['value']
    numvotes = i['numvotes']
    print('Value:',value,'\n','Numvotes:',numvotes)
```

Output

```
Value: No necessary in-game text
 Numvotes: 32
 Level: 1
Value: Some necessary text - easily memorized or small crib sheet
 Numvotes: 0
 Level: 2
Value: Moderate in-game text - needs crib sheet or paste ups
 Numvotes: 0
 Level: 3
Value: Extensive use of text - massive conversion needed to be playable
 Numvotes: 0
 Level: 4
Value: Unplayable in another language
 Numvotes: 0
 Level: 5
--------------------------------------------
Value: 2
 Numvotes: 0
Value: 3
 Numvotes: 0
Value: 4
 Numvotes: 0
Value: 5
 Numvotes: 1
Value: 6
 Numvotes: 6
Value: 8
 Numvotes: 15
Value: 10
 Numvotes: 10
Value: 12
 Numvotes: 0
Value: 14
 Numvotes: 0
Value: 16
 Numvotes: 0
Value: 18
 Numvotes: 0
Value: 21 and up
 Numvotes: 0
```